# delete partitions folders in hdfs older than N days

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, purge

I want to delete the partition folders which are older than N days.

The below command gives the folders which are exactly 50 days ago. I want the list of all folders which are less than 50 days

```
hadoop fs -ls /data/publish/DMPD/VMCP/staging/tvmcpr_usr_prof/chgdt=`date --date '50 days ago' +\%Y-\%m-\%d`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with solr hdfsfindtool:

```
hadoop jar /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/solr/contrib/mr/search-mr-job.jar org.apache.solr.hadoop.HdfsFindTool -find /data/publish/DMPD/VMCP/staging/tvmcpr_usr_prof -mtime +50 | xargs hdfs dfs -rm -r -skipTrash
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with a `bash` script

```
today=`date +'%s'`
hdfs dfs -ls /data/publish/DMPD/VMCP/staging/tvmcpr_usr_prof/ | grep "^d" | while read line ; do 
dir_date=$(echo ${line} | awk '{print $6}')
difference=$(( ( ${today} - $(date -d ${dir_date} +%s) ) / ( 24*60*60 ) ))
filePath=$(echo ${line} | awk '{print $8}')

if [ ${difference} -lt 50 ]; then
    echo "${filepath}"
fi
done
```