# Hadoop - Delete only files older than X days

Tags: shell, hadoop, hdfs

I want to write a data retention shell script which when given two inputs - base directory and retention period(in days) deletes ONLY FILES(not directories) older than the retention period. I have searched on the Internet and there have been some solutions but they are listing the directories and deleting them based on the modification time.

But a directory may have a very old timestamp but may contain recently updated files.

How do I proceed? The `mindepth` and `maxdepth` option in `find` command do not work in HDFS.

The base directory may have multiple sub-directories which may have sub-directories and so on.

`base` directory is `/user/abhikaushik`

Then we have sub folders in the form of `yyyy/mm/dd/hh` like `base/2017/04/23/22`
or `base/studies/programming/file1.txt` and so on

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43889792/delete-partitions-folders-in-hdfs-older-than-n-days/43913326#43913326

Comment: @philantrovert It is not a duplicate. In your answer, you are listing sub-directories within a directory and deleting them. What I want is to go into the maximum depth of all directories and check files there and delete them.

Comment: That's why I said "possible duplicate". Take that as a reference. If you use `grep -v` instead of `grep` it will show you anything but directories, and you can achieve maximum depth by using `hdfs dfs -ls -R`. I'm sure you'll work it out. Comment here or on that answer for any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete files older than 10days on HDFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44235019/delete-files-older-than-10days-on-hdfs)

Answer (score 13):

How about this:

`hdfs dfs -ls -R /MY/BASE/DIR/PATH | grep  "^-" | tr -s " " | cut -d' ' -f6-8 | awk 'BEGIN{ RETENTION_DAYS=10; LAST=24*60*60*RETENTION_DAYS; "date +%s" | getline NOW } { cmd="date -d'\''"$1" "$2"'\'' +%s"; cmd | getline WHEN; DIFF=NOW-WHEN; if(DIFF > LAST){ print $3 }}'`

where,

List all the files recursively:

> hdfs dfs -ls -R /MY/BASE/DIR/PATH

Get only *FILES* from the list:

> grep  "^-"

Replace extra spaces:

> tr -s " "

Get the required columns:

> cut -d' ' -f6-8

Processing using awk:

> awk

Initialize the DIFF duration and current time:

> RETENTION_DAYS=10;
>
> LAST=24*60*60*RETENTION_DAYS;
>
> "date +%s" | getline NOW

Create a command to get the epoch value for timestamp of the file on HDFS:

> cmd="date -d'\''"$1" "$2"'\'' +%s";

Execute the command to get epoch value for HDFS file:

> cmd | getline WHEN;

Get the time difference:

> DIFF=NOW-WHEN;

Print the output depending upon the difference:

> if(DIFF > LAST){ print $3 }}

### --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

---

**Proceed once you are sure that above command lists the files you want to delete**

Now, instead of doing a `print` operation in last step, you can do what you actually want i.e. delete the older FILES, like this:

`hdfs dfs -ls -R /MY/BASE/DIR/PATH | grep  "^-" | tr -s " " | cut -d' ' -f6-8 | awk 'BEGIN{ RETENTION_DAYS=10; LAST=24*60*60*RETENTION_DAYS; "date +%s" | getline NOW } { cmd="date -d'\''"$1" "$2"'\'' +%s"; cmd | getline WHEN; DIFF=NOW-WHEN; if(DIFF > LAST){ system("hdfs dfs -rm -r -skipTrash "$3 ) }}'`

You just need to change the values for `/MY/BASE/DIR/PATH` and `RETENTION_DAYS` depending upon your requirement (here its 10 days).

Hope this helps!

Comment: It worked for me. But it kept the directory name. The files inside the directory were deleted, but the directory remained.

Comment: Above solution works only for files because it has `grep  "^-"`. You can delete directories also by replacing it with `grep  -v  "^Found"`. But remember that, now it'll delete the directories also no matter whats the timestamp of files inside that directory.

Answer (score 2):

Try this-

Delete all the files created in 2017-0 to 8.

```
hadoop fs -rm -r `hadoop fs -ls -R <location> | grep '.*2017-[0-8].*' | awk '{print $8}'`
```

Answer (score 0):

Small improvement from Rahul Sharma's answer :

```
hdfs dfs -rm -r `hadoop fs -ls -R <location> | grep -v '.*2023-.*' | awk '{print $8}' | tac`
```

This will delete the files that were not made in 2023 (not part of the improvement but it could help someone).

At the end of the command we invert the list with `tac` because the `ls` will first show the folder and it's sub folders and files :

```
TOTO/
TOTO/TITI/
TOTO/TITI/TUTU.parquet
TOTO/TITI/TATA.parquet
```

This way you will delete the files and folders in the right orders and not get errors that the file is not found :

```
TOTO/TITI/TATA.parquet
TOTO/TITI/TUTU.parquet
TOTO/TITI/
TOTO/
```